# Sed find and replace expression works with literal but not with variable interpolation

Tags: bash, sed

For the following MVCE:

```sh
echo "test_num: 0" > test.txt
test_num=$(grep 'test_num:' test.txt  | cut -d ':' -f 2)
new_test_num=$((test_num + 1))

echo $test_num
echo $new_test_num

sed -i "s/test_num: $test_num/test_num: $new_test_num/g" test.txt
cat test.txt

echo "sed -i "s/test_num: $test_num/test_num: $new_test_num/g" test.txt"

sed -i "s/test_num: 0/test_num: 1/g" test.txt
cat test.txt
```

Which outputs

```sh
0 # parsed original number correctly
1 # increment the number
test_num: 0 # sed with interpolated variable, does not work
sed -i s/test_num: 0/test_num: 1/g test.txt # interpolated parameter looks right
test_num: 1 # ???
```

Why does `sed -i "s/test_num: $test_num/test_num: $new_test_num/g" test.txt` not produce the expected result when `sed -i "s/test_num: 0/test_num: 1/g" test.txt` works just fine in the above example?

Comment: The problem is that your `test_num` has a leading space, so the first sed command doesn't find the regex (`test_num: $test_num`) in the file.

Comment: Also, in the last `echo` command, the double-quotes don't nest, so the part involving the variable isn't in quotes at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there is a white space in `${test_num}`. Therefore in your `sed` there should not be an empty space between the colon and your variable.

Also I guess you should surround your variable with curly bracket `{}` to increase readability.

```
sed "s/test_num:${test_num}/test_num: ${new_test_num}/g" test.txt 
test_num: 1
```

If you just want the number in `${test_num}`, you can try something like:

```
grep 'test_num:' test.txt | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}'
```

`awk` allows to specify delimiter with more than 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `grep|cut` you can also use `sed`.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

exec <<EOF
test_num: 0
EOF

grep 'test_num:' | cut -d ':' -f 2

exec <<EOF
test_num: 0
EOF

sed -n 's/^test_num: //p'
```

Answer (score 0):

When using regexp replace in `sed` there is special meaning to `$` .

Suggesting to rebuild your `sed` command segments as follow:

```
sed -i 's/test_num: '$test_num'/test_num: '$new_test_num'/g' test.txt
```

Other option, use `echo` command to expand variables in `sed` command.

```
sed_command=$(echo "s/test_num:${test_num}/test_num: ${new_test_num}/g")
sed -i "$sed_command" test.txt
```